# What does resetAbort do?

Tags: c#, reset, thread-abort, threadabortexception

Hi I have following test code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(Work);
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        t.Abort();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        t.Abort();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        t.Abort();
        t.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }

    static void Work()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i<10)
        {
            try
            {
                while(true);
            }
            catch(ThreadAbortException)
            {
                Thread.ResetAbort();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("I will come back!");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime, when there is an abort, Thread.ResetAbort() will be executed. I wonder what this ResetAbort does. Because when I run it, I saw the following output:
I will come back!
I will come back!
I will come back!
And I didn't see the output "End" - it seems this program didn't end at all. Do you know why? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cancels the request to abort the thread. [As indicated here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resetabort.aspx) So in this case the loop will continue and the thread should still be alive.

Comment: Oh..I omit the inner while loop...so the program never ends. Thanks!

Comment: It cancels the request to abort - so it will resume from the inner while(true), am I right?

Comment: No because an exception was thrown so it won't be in there anymore but it's really hard to speculate because this code is....strange.

Answer (score 1):

The others' answer about `ResetAbort` is correct.  The reason why "End" isn't output is because `t.Join()` never returns.  This is because your thread is only attempted to be aborted three times, and your loop contains 10 attempts at infinite loops.  `Join` returns when the target thread completes running its delegate, and yours doesn't complete.

Comment: Yes! It's my bad. Sorry! Thank you at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

ResetAborts cancels the abort request for a thread